# Mapping domain model to logical model using automapper

Tags: asp.net, mapping, automapper

My problem is with loop navigation property during mapping domain models to logical models using Automapper.

Here are examples of domain models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }      
}

public class Payment
{
    public long PaymentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

And here logical models:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PaymentModel> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentModel
{
    public long PaymentId { get; set; }

    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
}
```

And now. When i perform mapping using automapper like this:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerModel> GetCustomers()
{
    return _db.Customer.ProjectTo<CustomerModel>();
}
```

}

I'm getting System.StackOverflowException. As i understand it's because of loop in navigations. After mapping Customer to CustomerModel Automapper is trying to map ICollection Payments to IEnumerable Payments but because of navigation to CustomerModel inside PaymentModel class its looping..
I know i could fix it by creating 2nd logical model (class Payment2)without navigation property to CustomerModel but i would have to perform another mapping. And with 50 domain models with navigation property it would be annoying.

Is there any other mayby easier and faster solution?

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework to generate domain models?

Comment: Funny, I can project similar DTOs with AutoMapper no problemo. No tricks with max depth or lazy loading disabled. Looks like the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change type of `Payments` property:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public List<PaymentModel> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

And manually map it:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Payment, PaymentModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer, opt => opt.Ignore());
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Payments.ForEach(p => p.Customer = dest));
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately it will work only in case when mapping is started from `Customer` entity:

```
CustomerModel model = Mapper.Map<CustomerModel>(entity);
```

If you don't care about perfomance, try `DynamicMap`:

```
CustomerModel model = Mapper.DynamicMap<CustomerModel>(entity);
```

Comment: Problem is that i need that Customer Customer property inside PaymentModel's class to use it for other actions

Comment: @user3037147, you're right, it will work only if we map `Customer` entity. Is `Mapper.DynamicMap` call appropriate for you?

Comment: Well i gave up with automapper. It seems like my own mapping is more appropriate for my project

Comment: @user3037147, sad to see this. `Mapper.DynamicMap` worked in my particular test.